# Primary phone of type Mobile doesn't show in the Primary phone profile field

Tags: civicrm

When you add a field of phone type Primary in a profile for a contact, if that phone type is Mobile, it does not show appear. Contact details:

[image]

Profile field detail:

[image]

Profile view detail:
[image]

Any suggestions?

I expected to see the mobile phone number appearing in the Primary phone field. In other words, the phone type should be irrelevant; all that should matter is that it is the Primary one. If I make the type Phone as opposed to Mobile, the phone number appears in the Primary field.

Comment: I can't replicate that on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/profile/edit?gid=16&reset=1 where i made a profile to check. if you can replicate, then i suggest you re-ask on the civicrm thread at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Thanks for that. I looked at the profile in Demo, and indeed, the issue doesn't seem to be there. More research is clearly needed.

Comment: I can reproduce it in the Demo environment - the profile there specifies Primary Mobile. If you say Primary Phone, you can't see it. I'll re-ask as you suggest.